# What is the number of ways in which I can select 17 balls from an urn containing 30 balls?

Tags: combinatorics

I have an urn that contains 30 balls with 10 coloured white, 10 coloured black and the remaining coloured red. Each ball is numbered, from 1 to 10: that is I have red balls numbered 1 to 10, black balls numbered 1 to 10 and white balls numbered 1 to 10. In how many ways can I select 17 balls such that I select a minimum of 4 red balls, 4 black balls and 4 white balls?

I need the quickest method to find the above out. There are long methods of solving it where I find the number of scenarios that violate the condition, such as those scenarios with 3 red balls or no black balls; these I subtract from the total number of ways of choosing 17 balls from the urn.

But is there a quicker way to solve this question?

(EDIT: All balls are now numbered. Please accept my apologies.)

(I will say this: The above problem is not a home-work problem from school.)

Comment: Now, take this with a grain of salt because I'm not an expert in combinatorics (thus this is but a comment and not an answer), but if you originally have $\binom{30}{17}$ and then you take out the $4$ red, black and white balls, then don't you simplify to $\binom{18}{5}$?

Comment: @JosephEck No, it doesn't work See my comment on Tamojit Maiti's answer.

Comment: Do you care which white balls you select, or only how many?  It sounds like you want just the number of compositions of $17$ into three parts of at least $4$.

Comment: @RossMillikan you’re right. Let me change the question a little.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 21 composition of 17:

$17 = 4+4+9 , 17 = 4+5+8, .... , 17=9+4+4$

However, some of have the same structure are equivalent and we may take 3 or 6 of them at a time:

$ 3  \binom{10}{4} \binom{10}{4} \binom{10}{9} + 
 3  \binom{10}{5} \binom{10}{5} \binom{10}{7}  + 
 3  \binom{10}{6} \binom{10}{6} \binom{10}{5}  + 
 6  \binom{10}{4} \binom{10}{5} \binom{10}{8}  + 
 6  \binom{10}{4} \binom{10}{6} \binom{10}{7}  $

Answer (score 1):

You can select 4 red balls from 10 white balls in $10\choose4$ ways. Similarly, for white and black balls.

So, we can select 4 red, 4 black and 4 white balls in ${{10}\choose {4}}* {{10}\choose {4}}*{{10}\choose {4}} $ ways.

We now have $5$ balls to select, from $30-12=18$ balls. This can be done in $18\choose5$ ways.

The answer thus becomes ${{10}\choose {4}}* {{10}\choose {4}}*{{10}\choose {4}} *{{18\choose5}}$ ways.

Comment: There's double counting here.  Suppose you select 5 red balls $a,b,c,d,e.$  You are counting the case where the first $4$ balls selected are $a,,b,c,d$ and the fifth $e$ and also the case where there first four are $b,c,d,e$ and the fifth $a,$ and so on, so this case is counted $5$ times.

Comment: But all balls are identical, right?

Comment: If the balls are indistinguishable, then you shouldn't be counting things like $\binom{10}{4}$ at all.  That only makes sense if we care *which* $4$ red balls we select.

Answer (score 1):

If the balls are identical you want the number of compositions of $17$ from three parts with each part being at least $4$ and at most $10$.  In this case you can subtract $3$ from each number and ask the number of  [strong compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) of $8$ from three parts of at most $7$ and we note that the upper limit is no problem.  You can use [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) to put the eight stars in a row and choose two of the seven gaps to change colors.  You have $7 \choose 2$ ways to pick the balls.

Comment: For the updated question, see nbegginer's answer

Comment: Can you please share the link to the answer?

Comment: It is another answer to this question